# an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, tkinter

So i'm making toolbar in tkinter, and don't have idea what's wrong with this code (I posted only most important things). I searched for sollution, but haven't found.

Edit:
But exFunc needs to take two strings

```
from tkinter import *    

def exFunc(x, y):
    with open("config.txt", "w") as file:
        pass

buttonName = Button(command= lambda: exFunc(1Entry.get(), 2Entry.get()))

#1Entry and 2Entry are just tkinter entries
```

Comment: `1Entry` is not a valid python identifier for starters

Comment: Your code doesn't even come close to working. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Bryan i posted only things that can cause problems

Answer (score 0):

`get()` returns a string by default. You can convert it to an integer with the `int` function:

```
buttonName = Button(command=lambda: exFunc(int(1Entry.get()), int(2Entry.get())))
```